# Convert Date to Year and Month

Tags: android, date

I am writing an application in which I have to display a date . Now I want to convert that date into Year and Month from the Current Date.

**My Date is Like - 29/03/2017.**

I want to convert this date into Year and Months.

Sorry I think you are not able to understand my question. I want the Difference of current date and above date in year and months.

Sorry for my explanation.

Comment: Have a look at the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer using Calender class .

First i find the difference between two days and using that days i found the years and months.

Here i post my code, which i think help to others.

```
int days = Integer.parseInt(Utility.getDateDiffString("29/03/2017"));
int years = days/365;
int remainingDays = days - (365*years);
int months = remainingDays/30;
```

**getDateDiffString() Method. In this method we need to pass end date**

```
public static String getDateDiffString(String endDate)
    {
        try
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date dateTwo = dateFormat.parse(endDate); 

            long timeOne = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            long timeTwo = dateTwo.getTime();
            long oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            long delta = (timeTwo - timeOne) / oneDay;

            if (delta > 0) {
                return "" + delta + "";
            }
            else {
                delta *= -1;
                return "" + delta + "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Joda](http://joda-time.sf.net/) Time and compute a Period between two LocalDate values (which is what you've got here) using months and years as the units.

example

```
LocalDate dob = new LocalDate(1992, 12, 30);
        LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2010, 12, 29);

        Period period = new Period(dob, date, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
        System.out.println(period.getYears() + " years and " +
                           period.getMonths() + " months");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do i need some library for Joda time ?

Comment: just include the binary jar for Joda to your project libs folder

Answer (score 0):

Use Java [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to get year from date

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM");
System.out.println(simpleDateformat.format(c.getTime()));


To get difference between two date

int diffInDays = (int)( (newerDate.getTime() - olderDate.getTime()) 
                 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) )
```

Comment: I want the Difference of current date and above date in year and months.

Answer (score 0):

long timeDiff =  (d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());

```
    String diff=String.format("%d year(s) %d day(s) %d hour(s) %d min(s) %d sec(s)",(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeDiff)/365),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeDiff)%365,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)
            - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
            .toDays(timeDiff)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff)
            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
            .toHours(timeDiff)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeDiff)
            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
            .toMinutes(timeDiff)));
    System.out.println(diff);
```

Specify correct date here in d1 & d2.Then you will get right answer of difference

Comment: I want the Difference of current date and above date in year and months.

Answer (score 0):

if your date's format is fixed, you can do it like this :

String myDate = "29/03/2017";

String newDate = myDate.subString(6, 10) + "-" + myDate.subString(3, 5)

Answer (score 0):

this method to convert the normal string to date format

```
String currentDateString = "02/27/2012 17:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date currentDate = sd.parse(currentDateString);
```

after that you get the formal method

Answer (score 0):

You Should use [SimpleDateFormate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) !

For Example:--- You can get time & Date as you want:-

```
                           Date email_date = m.getSentDate();// this is date which you are getting
            DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM yyyy");
            DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            String date_str=date.format(email_date);
            String time_str=time.format(email_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

First put your Date into a String variable as:

```
String dateToConvert = "29/03/2017";
```

Instantiate Calendar as:

```
Calendar convertedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Set that date to calendar

```
convertedDate.set(dateToConvert);<br/>
```

Then use this line:

```
String datePicked = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(convertedDate.getTime());
```

Output: Mar 29, 2017