# Date conversion to month and year in Android

Tags: android, datetime

I have a date in pattern `26/03/2013`. How can I get equivalent month and year like `March  2013` format in Android? My date is like `29-03-2017`

I want to convert this date into year and months.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14081940/2345913) or you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
try {
    String dateString = "26/03/2013";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);

    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
    String formattedDate = outputFormat.format(date);

    Log.d(TAG, "Got the date: " + formattedDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Aw you're making me blush! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String strdate = "26/03/2013";    
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date yourdate = sdf.parse(str);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMMM yyyy" );  
    String yourfinaldate = sdf.format(yourdate);
```